# Spring Boot Actuator endpoints: Pause & Resume, what do they do?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

We have been looking at the Spring Boot Actuator Pause and Resume endpoints and cannot find any indication they are doing anything. Documentation indicates they run stop and start on the ApplicationContext, respectively, but there is never any indication in the logs or loss of functionality once pause has been activated.

What are they used for?

Answer (score 2):

By default,  actuator endpoint `GET /health` returns health status `UP`.

`POST /pause` will turn `DOWN` `GET /health` status.

Likewise, `POST /resume` will turn back health status to `UP`.